# Blinding factor SEAL

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, multiparty-computation, blinding

For a protocol, I need to blind a ciphertext. I am not sure how to choose the blinding factor. How should I choose the range? What should I consider to offer security?

I am using CKKS scheme, the one in SEAL.

Comment: You might consider putting in more details about what you're doing; for example, what cryptosystem are you using?

Comment: I am using CKKS scheme, the one in SEAL.

Comment: An answer has been provided to the question by poncho here in the comments. If there are more things unclear, please comment below.

Comment: @dilot  Your response to Poncho's comment merely repeated part of your question.  If you flesh your question out a bit, you will probably get an answer.